# How to add a element into array without overwriting the previous one

Tags: javascript, cypress, ui-automation

In my script I want to save the form submit url into json file and this is happening multiple times so I want to save every form submit url into json file automatically.

I have tried this with one below

```js
proposalUrl() {

    let URLArray = []

    cy.url().then(function (el) {

        //cy.log(el)
        
        URLArray.push(el)

        cy.writeFile('cypress\\test_data\\2Wheeler\\url.json', {

            ProposalSubmitUrl:URLArray

        })
    })
}
```

in the url.json I got suppose example so when we run my script I get the same url like url_one.

```json
{
  "ProposalSubmitUrl": [
    "url_one"
  ]
}
```

And I want to get the every url when I am running the script like below

```json
{
  "ProposalSubmitUrl": [
    "url_one",
    "url_two",
    "url_three"
  ]
}
```

This I want

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that every time your code runs, the json file doesn't change but the `URLArray` is regenerated again and again.

The key is to access the content of the json file, push into the array we got from the content, and then rewrite the json file:

```js
cy.readFile('cypress\\test_data\\2Wheeler\\url.json').then((json) => {
 
    let URLArray = json.ProposalSubmitUrl

    cy.url().then(function (el) {

        //cy.log(el)
     
        URLArray.push(el)

        cy.writeFile('cypress\\test_data\\2Wheeler\\url.json', {

            ProposalSubmitUrl: URLArray

        })
    })
}
});
```